# 3A Current Distribution

Tags: current, current-measurement, wire

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ql0Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using a 5V 3A wall adapter. I have stripped the output end and connected it to a terminal block. I am rerouting the current to two places: a standard breadboard and the Raspberry Pi. When I use the multimeter to measure the current I see readings of 0 and then sudden spikes to 2A.

Why am I not seeing anything close to 3A? I am measuring the current directly from the adapter's PWR and GND wires. Please let me know if any additional info can help.

I also get PWR warning issues from the Raspberry Pi but I believe this may be a result of the fluctuating current readings OR the fact I am using 26 AWG cable (rated max 300 mA when the Pi needs 1A).

Answer (score 1):

The Pi needs 500mA DC, not 1A (depending on the model, actually).

The way you have connected the current meter sounds wrong - using a multimeter as an ammeter you must put the device in SERIES along the PWR output wire, not to ground.

You have probably damaged your multimeter or blown it's ammeter fuse.

The next thing is, place a large (100uf -> 1000uF) capacitor just where the Raspberry Pi is connected, to help it deal with pulsed current requirements.

You should also place a large capacitor on the breadboard where the power connection comes into it. This technique is called *power supply decoupling*.

You should indeed increase the size of the wire carrying current to the Raspberry Pi by the way, even just two strands of AWG26 run together but twisted at each end would do fine.

You should not "see" 3A unless you actually have a 3A load. The Pi like I said will only draw about 500mA DC in normal conditions. Unless you have something else to act as a 2.5A load, you will never see the wall wart putting out 3A. Another thing is, don't trust crappy wall warts. The next thing is, if you short circuit the output (like with an ammeter from PWR to GND..) the Wall Wart may go into protection mode to protect itself, and thus brown-out the R-Pi.

Comment: WOW thank you for the amazing explanation. I will do the capacitor suggestions right away. I assumed RPi takes 1A because It has a max 700mA current consumption at worst case.

Comment: @presish yes that is probably when running at 100% CPU during heavy and prolonged computation. Most current consumed is very fast spikes, which capacitors deal with NOT the power supply (the supply basically cannot deal with it, certainly not at the end of a long wire, and otherwise because power supplies are often slow to react)

Comment: I have the 26AWG cables soldered to a stripped microUSB previously used to charge a cell phone. This microUSB seems to have a AWG higher than 26 since the wires are much thinner.. could this also be an issue? I could not find a microUSB with thicker cables.

Comment: @presish well the USB standard doesn't really specify more than 1.5A, and you CAN put 1.5A through thin wire, it will just get hot. And you will drop voltage. You do know you can pump 1000 amps through a needle yes? The only issue is the heat generated, and when you say 26AWG is only 'rated' to carry 300mA that is not true. The ratings are only for allowing a 10 degree Celsius rise above ambient - meaning you can do way more than that, it will just get hot (and like i said, drop voltage due to resistance and low surface area).

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the needle and 1000 amps!! I didn't know that the rating was based on temperature. So I conclude that the PWR issue on the RPi is from current fluctuations. I will add those caps to the breadboard and RPi and hopefully that solves the power issues.

Comment: @presish I should mention that the needle would melt in less than 1 second, probably exploding into gas and killing everyone around it. LOL

Comment: LOL ya that is good to point out before people go testing that experiment.

Comment: @presish you may want to wait, and also prove that my advice works, before accepting my answer..

Comment: OK no problem. I will see how the suggestions pan out over extended testing.

Comment: So the capacitors did not solve the issue of power warnings on the Pi... the capacitors actually made the RPi more sensitive to inputs. Before the decoupling capacitors, I would only get the power warning when I run a program/something more intensive... now I get the power warning after each keystroke.

Comment: @presish lol what the.. what capacitors are you using? can you update the question to show your wiring diagram? Are you still using an ammeter? There could be something else strange happening here

Comment: I don't know if that circuit helps at all. The extra wires are the other terminals on the terminal block (unused).

Comment: @presish remove the un-used wires if they do not add anything useful to the circuit diagram. It looks reasonable enough, but perhaps a smaller 100uF and 10uF could be put in there with the larger cap. Large capacitors are sometimes "slow" so their effect may be less useful in some cases, than a smaller "faster" capacitor.

Comment: a smaller cap in series or parallel with the 1000uF??

Comment: @presish parallel. From Raspbery Pi Vin to GND.

Comment: how does that work actually? You said the larger cap might not be useful yet we leave it on and add a smaller cap...

Comment: @presish you ALWAYS need a large cap, especially when you are supplying from a long ways off down a wire. The small caps are there for digital pulsed currents. The large cap is to deal with voltage sag for longer periods of current draw. But a condition of DC current going through a long wire can NEVER be fixed, no matter how many capacitors you have. Can you use a multimeter and see the voltage at the Vin to the RPI with reference to ground, and tell me the result?

Comment: since we are connecting the smaller cap in parallel to the larger cap... can't I just use a larger cap? connecting them in parallel only increases capacitor value...

Comment: @presish It does indeed increase the capacitance in total. But that is not how capacitors behave at fast speeds. Trust me, i'm an engineer. lol

Comment: ok cool thanks! I am a new engineer too, anything for me to learn is great advice!

Comment: the power warning is still there but it seems to tolerate a little more before outputting a warning... does that mean the smaller cap needs to increase?

Comment: @presish what is the voltage at the Vin to the Rpi?

Comment: The Vin for the RPi is 5V

Comment: @presish you don't happen to have an oscilloscope would you? That will show you what the 5V looks like (it could be super noisy, which triggers the warning, but otherwise things still work). Can you test with some other 5V supply and see if it does the same?

Comment: I do have an oscilloscope! I will check that out.

Comment: I do have an oscilloscope! I will check that out... I actually have used another power supply already and there are no power warning at all... I am not sure exactly what part of the new adapter can be causing a power warning... it may be a result of the soldering of the power adapter to the terminal block... I am not entirely sure

Comment: with the power turned off, can you try to measure the resistance from as far up the power supply as you can (the first bit of exposed metal possible close to the power pack output) to the R-Pi's input terminal? There may be a bad solder joint, and anything more than 1 Ohm is bad, basically. The wires should all be less than 1 or 2 Ohms in total. @presish  lol I keep forgetting to tag you in my comments

Comment: I have found multiple areas of the adapter in which there is greater than 1 Ohm resistance... lots of bad soldering I am assuming... what can I do to reach the 1-2 Ohm values? Maybe I have too much solder?

Comment: @presish well assuming you measured the same "wire" end to end, (not referenced to ground) and there was more than 1-2 ohms of resistance, there could indeed be bad solder joints or high contact resistance somewhere (in the terminals). The solder joints should look shiny, not dull and grey. You must heat up the joints until they are shiny and wet looking, and if you have flux you should put some on there too. Also try to use solder with lead in it. Can you take a picture of your setup by the way? It may help in some way. You would add that to the main question.